# I want to limit the resources of the docker daemon

Tags: docker

I have a server intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz × 32 with 1007gb memory and 20tb hard disk I have a docker in this server, I created a 25 container Cloudera (quickstart) 18 container of 25 is running the others stop it and i will create more than 50 container but now I can't I think is about the resources of docker how can I manage and increase the resources of docker from this server? and if the docker takes all the resources how can fix my problem to continue to create container Cloudera note: Cloudera container has 2 port the (hue) port is running but the (solr) port is not running plz reply when you can I need to fix my problem and thank you

Comment: Just check official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the environment, so there is no straight answer but keep reading.
Docker is based on cgroups. The CPU will be distributed among the running containers. By default the value is 1024.

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker/cpu.shares
1024
```

So, if we have 2 containers, one for the database and one more for the web server

```
sudo docker run -c 614 -dit --name db postgres /postgres.sh
sudo docker run -c 410 -dit --name web nginx /nginx.sh
```

Will give 60% to the db container (614 is 60% of 1024) and 40% to the web container.

You cannot give an overall limit, but you can restrict the set of CPUs that the container runs on using `--cpuset` [mentioned here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-constraints-on-resources).

Also you may look into this for [reference](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/)

Comment: thank but you tell me about another container , my question is about container Cloudera quickstart i have very big number of resources is about 32 cpus and 1007g ram and i cant create more than 16 container the number 17 is blocked ?? plz i want solution